# Pyspark Scheduled jobs is throwing out of memory error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have Created a scheduler that will execute the spark jobs.
When I am trying to execute the jobs via scheduler it is throwing OOM error after few run but when I am trying to execute those jobs independently or few jobs it will not throw any error.

scheduler:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ONE_HOUR = 3600
    FIVE_MINUTES = 300

    scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)


    def periodic(scheduler, interval, action, actionargs=()):
        scheduler.enter(interval, 1, periodic,
                        (scheduler, interval, action, actionargs))
        action(*actionargs)


    periodic(scheduler, ONE_HOUR, spark_flatten_a1)
    periodic(scheduler, ONE_HOUR, spark_flatten_a2)
    periodic(scheduler, ONE_HOUR, spark_flatten_a3)
    periodic(scheduler, ONE_HOUR, spark_flatten_a4)
    periodic(scheduler, ONE_HOUR, spark_flatten_a5)
    periodic(scheduler, ONE_HOUR, spark_flatten_a6)
    periodic(scheduler, ONE_HOUR, spark_flatten_a7)
    periodic(scheduler, ONE_HOUR, spark_flatten_a8)
    periodic(scheduler, ONE_HOUR, spark_flatten_a9)
    periodic(scheduler, ONE_HOUR, spark_flatten_a10)
    periodic(scheduler, ONE_HOUR, spark_flatten_a11)
    periodic(scheduler, FIVE_MINUTES, spark_flatten_a12)
    periodic(scheduler, FIVE_MINUTES, spark_flatten_a13)
    periodic(scheduler, FIVE_MINUTES, spark_flatten_a14)
    periodic(scheduler, FIVE_MINUTES, spark_flatten_a15)
    scheduler.run()
```

Sample pyspark job for spark_flatten_a1

```
def create_app_context():
    '''
    Creating spark context
    '''
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("flatten-a1") \
        .master(config.master)\
        .config('spark.jars','mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar')\
        .getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")
    return spark

def spark_flatten_a1():
    '''
    This function create a flattened table using spark
    '''
    _begin = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    logging.warning('++++++ Running app: flatten-a1 ++++++ {}'.format(_begin))
    # Building spark session for app
    ss = create_app_context()
    connector = MysqlConnector(host=config.host,
                               username=config.user,
                               password=config.password,
                               dbname=config.database)
    q = '''   Mysql query that will return data  '''
    # Getting the dataframe
    df = connector.read_and_return_as_df(spark= ss,
                                         query= q)
    try:
        # This will overwrite the table in single db transaction
        connector.write_dataframe(df=df,
                              table_name='a1',
                              mode='overwrite')
    except Exception as error:
        logging.error('Error while writing the dataframe back to mysql')
    ss.stop()
    _end = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    print('Time Taken: ',_end-_begin)
    logging.warning('++++++ Shutting app: flatten-a1 ++++++ ')
```

Code for all the jobs (a1 to a15) is similar to a1.

I have checked in the Spark UI all the SQL looks good.
Help me to resolve the OOM error

Any suggestions are more than welcome

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I am using JAMS scheduler.